# Swift: Can't add value to dictionary member of struct

Tags: dictionary, struct, swift

I can't add a value to a dictionary that is a member of a struct. For example, this:

```
struct S {
  var d = [String:Int]()

  func f() {
    d["Hello"] = 0
  }
}
```

results in this error:

```
'@lvalue $T6' is not identical to '(String, Int)'
```

Changing `struct` to `class`, or moving the declaration of `d` into function scope removes the error.

I imagine this is a bug, but I don't know. Is there some logic to this I don't understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to mark the method with `mutating` keyword to indicate it does modify the struct

```
mutating func f() {
  d["Hello"] = 0
}
```

From [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)

> ### Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods
>
> Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the
> properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance
> methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or
> enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating
> behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change)
> its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes
> are written back to the original structure when the method ends. The
> method can also assign a completely new instance to its implicit self
> property, and this new instance will replace the existing one when the
> method ends.
>
> You can opt in to this behavior by placing the **mutating** keyword before
> the func keyword for that method:

Comment: Thanks! The error messages in Swift have a ways to go still.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be mutating for a struct?

```
Struct S {
  var d = [String:Int]()

  mutating func f() {
    d["Hello"] = 0
  }
```

I'm on mobile, so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll pull the answer.